# Why say Hashem wrote the torah?

Tags: theology, writing-printing, quotations

Why do people say Hashem wrote the torah, shouldn't it be He created it, made it, edited it, etc?

Comment: You could ask the question for any other anthropomorphisms of God

Comment: I would suggest looking at the heading for כתב from Sefer Kehillat Yaacov by Rabbi Yaacov Tzvi Yolles in the first heading. It explains the concept according to the Zohar and the Mikdash Melech.

Answer (score 9):

Hashem is the author of the Torah. Generally the author of a work writes it. Actually nowadays the author generally types it, nevertheless, we still say so and so "wrote" it. Who transcribed it or how they did so is incidental to who authored it.

In other words saying Hashem wrote the Torah is just a generic way to convey *in English* that Hashem is its author.

Comment: Very Well said Yirmeyahu

Comment: Another example: Stephen Hawking doesn't "write" his books, though that's the word we use.

Answer (score 0):

Well he dictated it to Moshe who wrote it,But it already existed in Shamayim as we know based on the story of Moshe going up to get it it by Kabbolos Hatorah and we also know that it was the blueprint for the world as we know Hashem looked into the torah and created the world.The closest thing I can think of where Hashem sort of wrote  was the question is asked if Moshe died on Shabbos how did he write the 12 sefer torahs for the Shevatim one answer is given is He use An Incantaion and they got written I guess you can call that Hashem wrote it.